# Why say זכרנו and מי כמוך with the ש״ץ during the week but not on ר״ה ויו״כ?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, aseres-yemei-teshuva, high-holidays

For the ten days from *Rosh Hashana* through *Yom Kipur*, we add four sentences to the *amida* (*sh'mone esre*), starting respectively with "זכרנו",‎ "מי כמוך",‎ "וכתוב", and "‏(ו)בספר".

I've noticed the following practice in multiple synagogues: **Between and excluding** *Rosh Hashana* and *Yom Kipur*, when the leader repeats the *amida*, the congregation recites those sentences. However, in those same congregations, there are many people who, **on** *Rosh Hashana* and *Yom Kipur*, when the leader repeats the *amida*, recite "וכתוב" and "‏(ו)בספר", but not "זכרנו" or "מי כמוך".

Moreover, this practice is reflected in the ArtScroll *machzor* (*nusach "S'farad"* for *Rosh Hashana* and for *Yom Kipur*), which indicates that the congregation and leader recite "וכתוב" and "בספר" but that the leader recites "זכרנו" and "מי כמוך".

**Why is the practice on *Rosh Hashana* and *Yom Kipur* different from the practice on the days between them?**

I seek a reason for the difference primarily; an early source for the difference would be icing on the cake.

Comment: Does the Artscroll indicate doing this during the week? What about reciting Nacheim or Aneinu with the Chazan? Or Yaaleh veYavo?

Comment: @DoubleAA ArtScroll IIRC has no indication of what to do during the week. (Thus, my indication that the practice is reflected in ArtScroll means the _yom tov_ practice only.) I hadn't checked the other additions you mention.

Comment: The Artscroll makes no distinction during the week b/w a silent Amida and the Chazarah so no indication of communal reading is there. FWIW where I daven, regardless of the machzor's (lack of) instruction, we sing each one communally each time even on R"H and Y"K.

Comment: Does the artscroll for RH and YK give the stated instructions at all tefillot or only those with elaborated repetitions (ie not RH Mincha)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, good question. I don't know. If anyone else knows, I'd appreciate that info in a comment. If in fact the instructions are different for _RH mincha_ (as I seem to think the common practice may be) than for the other _yom tov_ services, then I should edit the question accordingly. Actually, lemme close this question pending that info....

Comment: @msh210 This is a first that I've seen on M.Y. A moderator placing his own question on hold! Surely, Yom Kippur is approaching :-) G'mar Chatimah Tovah. I hope you discover the answer between tonight & tomorrow night.

Comment: @DanF, _g'mar chasima tova_ to you _im kol Yisrael achecha_.

Comment: @msh210 OK, I looked at Art Scroll Yom Kippur / Ashkenaz, during Yom Kippur. I see the confusion. For some reason, by *Zachreinu* & *Mi Chamocha*, Art scroll says "Chazan continues" (or something similar), whereas before it, it says "Cong. followed by chazzan". I would just attribute this to one of numerous vague ideas that Art Scroll has been known to do. I think they did that, b/c the bracha is on the same paragraph, and they don't want the cong. to say the bracha. I have no clue as to why they did that. At any rate, since there are no commentaries or other instructions, I would ignore it.

Comment: This seems much better asked than http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47484/759 perhaps merge that here?